# Separate frame sizes for size classes in xib

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, size-classes

Is it possible to set separate frame sizes for different size classes on a custom view in Xcode's interface builder?  For most properties this is done using the `+` button next to the property in the inspector menu, but this does not seem to be available currently for frame.  It's also not available for Row Height on a Table View Cell component.  Both of these seem like they would commonly vary between iPhone/iPad form factors, so I'm surprised not to see size class customization buttons for them.

[image]

Comment: You can add constraints and customize your constraints based on size class.